# using socket.io in sencha touch application

Tags: extjs, socket.io, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I want to use socket.io in my sencha touch application

I added socket.io in my app.json js array :

```
  "js": [
    {
        "path": "touch/sencha-touch.js",
        "x-bootstrap": true
    },
    {
        "path": "bootstrap.js",
        "x-bootstrap": true
    },
    {
        "path": "lib/socket.io.js"
    },
    {
        "path": "app.js",
        "bundle": true,  /* Indicates that all class dependencies are concatenated into this file when build */
        "update": "delta"
    }
```

here is where I want to create var socket :

```
 var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
```

when I open index.html in browser I get this error :

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: io
```

how can I fix my application?

Comment: Check your brower using chrome dev tools to check if socket.io is well included in the html

Comment: It's well included in my html head tag but still I get errors:
Cannot find module 'buffer'
Can't find variable: io

Comment: have you checked in the Network tab of dev tools if the response to "GET /lib/socket.io.js" is ok?